# create ViewModel to rename response of API and make it connected to datatable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, api, viewmodel

i have external API , i want to create a class [ViewModel] to rename names of Json response of API to avoid renaming all those properties in case of anything renamed in API

BranchVm.cs:

```
public class Branches
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Company_Name")]
    public int branchCompanyId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Branch_ar")]
    public string branchArName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Branch_en")]
    public string branchEnName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Manger_Name")]
    public int branchManager { get; set; }

}
```

API JsonResponse:

```
[
{
    "$id": "1",
    "branchId": 0,
    "branchArName": "ttt",
    "branchEnName": "tt", 
},
{
    "$id": "2",
    "branchId": 1,
    "branchArName": "الفرع الرئيسى",
    "branchEnName": "Main Branch",
},
]
```

I use DataTable to display the response in js file , How can i make connection between them ??

Comment: you are creating the API or you are consuming the API?

Comment: i have an API but it's not in the same project, So i have it's response only